# Angular 6 not updating the view after POST

Tags: angular, angular6

I just want to submit one input but angular doesn't update the list on the html component. I am using Web Api for backend.

Service:

```
getRanks(): Observable<Rank[]> {
   return this.http.get<Rank[]>(this.rankUrl);
}
```

Component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.getRanks();
}

newRank: any = {};

saveRank(rank: Rank) {
   this.rankService.addRank(rank).subscribe();
}

getRanks(): void {
   this.rankService.getRanks()
      .subscribe(
         ranks => {
           this.ranks = ranks;
   });
}
```

Component.html:

```
<div class="col-md-6 text-center">
<input  [(ngModel)]="newRank.Name">
   <button (click)="saveRank(newRank)">Save</button>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let rank of ranks"> {{rank.Name}}

</div>
```

I stripped the code as much as I could from the original one but it still behaves the same. I also commented everything that is not related to post and get methods.

I checked other answers and tried to use zone and `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default`

If I refresh the page then it shows up, so its submitted in the database but it doesn't show up after submission.

Any ideas? Any other info I should provide?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call the getRanks() function in the subscribe success function like this:

```
saveRank(rank: Rank) {
   this.rankService.addRank(rank)
    .subscribe(_ => this.getRanks());
}
```

Comment: I was pretty sure was a problem in subscribe, but I have never needed before to specify any other get method. Isn't supposed to do this by itself?

Comment: No. Please refer to the link bellow for more information about Angular Change Detection. https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Answer (score 1):

you need to refresh your ranks object. simply you can call `this.getranks();`

```
saveRank(rank: Rank) {
   this.rankService.addRank(rank).subscribe(_ => this.getRanks());
}
```

or

```
this.rankService.addRank(rank).subscribe( _=> ranks.push(rank));
```

Comment: Almost, but problem was I had to submit twice to get the list updated, which creates duplicate entries in database.

Comment: I am sorry I just missed the subscribe directive. I edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to all this.getRanks, add manually the item to the array "rank"

```
saveRank(rank: Rank) {
   this.rankService.addRank(rank)
    .subscribe(_ => this.ranks.push(rank)); //<--push the array
}
```

or change your API so, the API call to saveRank, return all the ranks